# How to Clear a Bitmap in VCL

Tags: c++builder, vcl, rad-studio

How to clear a bitmap that was declared in the .cpp as follows:

```
Graphics::TBitmap * Bitmap1 = new Graphics::TBitmap;
```

All the examples I find are for Firemonkey and there it seems quite simple

```
MyBitmap = new TBitmap(0,0);
...


MyBitmap->Clear(claWhite);
```

or

```
MyBitmap->ClearRect(MyRect);
```

But Clear() and ClearRect() are not members of TBitmap in VCL

I expect I should `delete Bitmap1;` in order to clear it, but then how to re-declare it, so that it is still global to all methods in the form?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to delete and recreate the `TBitmap`.  Simply draw a new image over top of it, for instance by using its [`Canvas->FillRect()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCanvas.FillRect) method (that is essentially what the FMX examples are doing), eg:

```
Bitmap1->Brush->Color = clWhite;
Bitmap1->Canvas->FillRect(Rect(0, 0, Bitmap1->Width, Bitmap1->Height));
```